# Div with same class draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a function that sends a notification to the page and I prepend a main div with the notification with, this is the function:

```
function showNotification_event2(notificationTitle, notificationContent, notificationColor, notificationSize) {
    console.log('trying to execute notification');

    var notificationArea = $('#notification_area');
    var notificationHtml;

    notificationHtml += '<div class="container">';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="col-md-' + notificationSize + ' col-centered">'; // column
    notificationHtml += '<div class="draggable panel panel-pink">';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: ' + notificationColor + '">';
    notificationHtml += notificationTitle;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-body">';
    notificationHtml += notificationContent;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '</div>'; // end column
    notificationHtml += '</div>';

    $("#notification_area").prepend(notificationHtml);
    $('.draggable').draggable();
}
```

As you can see I declare the .draggable draggable but it only works for the first notification that is created, is there any way I can get around this and make all div's with that class draggable?

HTML:

```
<div id="notification_area">
    <!-- Notificiations will automatically be added here. -->
</div>
```

Full code (changed a little since the previous edit):

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8181/');

var hasConnected = false;

function startWebSockets() {
    ws.onmessage = function (messageEvent) {
        onReceiveMessage(messageEvent.data);
    };

    ws.onopen = function () {
        onConnectionOpened();
    };

    ws.onclose = function () {
        onConnectionClosed();
    }
}

function onReceiveMessage(messageData) {
    var messageParts = messageData.includes('\\') ? messageData.split('\\') : messageData;

    if (messageData.includes("\\")) {
        if (messageParts[0] == "compose:show_custom_notification") {
            showBootstrapNotification(messageParts[1], messageParts[2], messageParts[3], messageParts[4]);   
        }
    }   
    else {
        if (messageData == "compose:authentication_complete") {
            console.log('Authentication to WebSocket server has been completed.');
        }

        if (messageData == "compose:authentication_failed") {
            sendMessage("client_identity_token " + habboSso);
        }
    }
}

function onConnectionOpened() {
    console.log('Connected to the WebSocket server.');
    hasConnected = true;

    sendMessage("client_identity_token " + habboSso);
}

function onConnectionClosed() {
    if (!hasConnected) {
        console.log('Failed to connect to the WebSocket server.');
    } 
    else {
        console.log('Your connection to the WebSocket server was unexpectedly closed.');
    }
}

function sendMessage(message) {
    if (hasConnected) {
        ws.send(message);
    }
}

startWebSockets();

function showBootstrapNotification(notificationTitle, notificationContent, notificationColor, notificationSize) {
    console.log('trying to execute notification');

    var notificationArea = $('#notification_area');
    var notificationHtml;

    const randomId = '' + new Date().getTime() + '_' + Math.random();

    notificationHtml += '<div class="col-md-' + notificationSize + ' col-centered">';
    notificationHtml += '<div id="' + randomId  + '" class="draggable panel panel-pink">';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: ' + notificationColor + '">';
    notificationHtml += notificationTitle;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-body">';
    notificationHtml += notificationContent;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '</div>';

    $("#notification_area").prepend(notificationHtml);

    setTimeout(function() {
        const myToBeDraggableDiv = $('#'+randomId);
        myToBeDraggableDiv.removeAttr('id');
        myToBeDraggableDiv.draggable();
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: when is actually you are firing this notification event as this might be the key.

Comment: It's a little hard to say that as I show the notification when the websocket server asks to display one, but I have been running it directly via Google Chrome's console window to save time actually sending it during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues :

- Repeatedly making the same element(s) draggable may be causing issues. Have you tried selecting only the newly added notification div and add it to the other draggables? (See the example)
- `var notificationHtml;` <-- This var appears to be a string that should be initialized with an empty string.
- There is already a reference created for the parent container: `var notificationArea = $('#notification_area');` and while appending content you can use this reference. (Not really a breaking error)

Fixing these your showBootstrapNotification function would be this :

```
function showBootstrapNotification(notificationTitle, notificationContent, notificationColor, notificationSize) {
    console.log('trying to execute notification');


    var notificationArea = $('#notification_area');
    var notificationHtml = '';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="col-md-' + notificationSize + ' col-centered">';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="draggable panel panel-pink">';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: ' + notificationColor + '">';
    notificationHtml += notificationTitle;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-body">';
    notificationHtml += notificationContent;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '</div>';

    const newNot = $(notificationHtml);
    notificationArea.prepend(newNot);
    newNot.draggable();
}
```

Comment: I tried your method and it's disabled every notification from being draggable.

Comment: Provide a working sample of your code so we can all see what's wrong.

Comment: I have edited my question with the full .js file content.

Comment: Ah my bad. Can you add a prefix since that's an invalid id starting with a number. As edited in the answer.  That may not fix your issue but definetely should not break.

Comment: Obviously, this **won't work** because `randomId` is defined as a **`constant`**, so its value won't change after first assignment. `let` is the way to go here.

Comment: In fact it is const by design. Because we don't want it to change later. The other const randomId is another const randomId :)

Comment: Even after adding a prefix it still doesn't let any div be draggable. const randomId = 'notificiationPrefix' + new Date().getTime() + '_' + Math.random();

Comment: There were some other issues in your code. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it a lot. I have accepted your answer.